# Add one hour forward to current time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

I'm working on my Python script to get the hours time.

When my current time is 8:30PM, I want to know how I can add the hour forward in the labels which it will be 9:00PM, 9:30PM?

Here is for example:

```
if (0 <= datetime.datetime.now().minute <= 29):
   self.getControl(4203).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':00' + time.strftime("%p"))
   self.getControl(4204).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':30' + time.strftime("%p"))
   self.getControl(4205).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':00' + time.strftime("%p"))
else:
   self.getControl(4203).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':30' + time.strftime("%p"))
   self.getControl(4204).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':00' + time.strftime("%p"))
   self.getControl(4205).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':30' + time.strftime("%p"))
```

When my current time is between 8:30PM and 8:59PM, the label with id `4203` will show 8:30PM, the label with id `4204` will show 8:00PM and the label with id `4205` will show 8:30PM. I want the labels to be display to something is like `8:30PM`, `9:00PM` and `9:30PM`.

Can you please tell me how I can add the one hour forward for the labels following with ids 4204 and 4205?

Comment: Please provide minimal examples. We don't know `self.getControl(...)` (and we don't need to know it for this context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make computations using seconds from epoch:

```
import time
t0 = time.time() # now (in seconds)
t1 = t0 + 60*30  # now + 30 minutes
t2 = t0 + 60*60  # now + 60 minutes

for t in [t0,t1,t2]:
   print time.strftime("%I %M %p",time.localtime(t))
```

output

```
09 57 PM
10 27 PM
10 57 PM
```

if you want to round the time to the previous half-hour, add this line:

```
t0 -= t0 % (30*60) # round down to previous half-hour
```

Answer (score 8):

For time offsets you can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
>>> import datetime

>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9, 21, 47, 6, 178534)

>>> datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 9, 22, 47, 16, 851338)
```

As for your code, here's an example with couple of improvements:

```
import datetime

# get current time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

# round to half hours
if (now.minute / 30):
    # minutes 30-59
    minute = 30
else:
    # minutes 00-29
    minute = 0
now = now.replace(minute=minute, second=0, microsecond=0)

def format(time):
    return time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + time.strftime(":%M%p")

# set labels
print(4203, format(now))
print(4204, format(now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)))
print(4205, format(now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)))
```

And here's the output:

```
(4203, '11:00PM')
(4204, '11:30PM')
(4205, '12:00AM')
```

Comment: i try to use like this: one_hour = datetime.strptime("%I").lstrip('0'), one_hour += datetime.timedelta(hours=1) print one_hour` i will get an error: `one_hour = datetime.strptime("%I").lstrip('0') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'`. Do you have any idea why I get the error?

Comment: @user3817638 You get an error because `datetime` module doesn't have a `strptime` function. But you can call it on a `datetime` object like so `datetime.datetime.now().strptime(...)`. As for your code, I have a rather hard time understanding what exactly which label should display.

Comment: @user3817638 Figured out what you wanted, kinda tired for today :) Added an example using `datetime.timedelta`, may come handy.